# How can I downgrade libgtkmm-2.4-1v5 to libgtkmm-2.4-1c2a?

Tags: apt, dpkg

I have an install that is demanding `libgtkmm-2.4-1c2a` as a dependency, although `apt-get` does not have it.  `apt-get` suggested `libgtkmm-2.4-1v5` instead, but this does not work.

I am running Ubuntu 16.  How do I downgrade?

EDIT:

Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Output of `apt-cache policy libgtkmm-2.4-1v5`:

```
libgtkmm-2.4-1v5:
  Installed: 1:2.24.4-2
  Candidate: 1:2.24.4-2
  Version table:
 *** 1:2.24.4-2 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

output of `sudo apt-get check`:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libflycapturegui2 : Depends: libgtkmm-2.4-1c2a but it is not installable
                     Depends: libglademm-2.4-1c2a but it is not installable
 libflycapturegui2-dev : Depends: libgtkmm-2.4-1c2a but it is not installable
                         Depends: libglademm-2.4-1c2a but it is not installable
```

running `apt-get -f install` did this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libflycapturegui2 libflycapturegui2-dev
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 2 to remove and 146 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 217420 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing libflycapturegui2-dev (2.9.3.43) ...
Removing libflycapturegui2 (2.9.3.43) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu9) ...
```

after which `sudo apt-get check` gives:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
```

Comment: Please update your post with the following information: name and origin of the package which you are going to  install and output of `apt-cache policy libgtkmm-2.4-1v5` and `sudo apt-get check`. By Ubuntu 16 do you mean 16.04 LTS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`libgtkmm-2.4-1c2a` is not available in 16.04, as you can see. It is available in 14.04, so you can either install 14.04 or ask the maintainers of the package you are trying to install to provide a package compatible with 16.04.

Comment: I installed Ubuntu 14 in the end.

Answer (score 0):

The [flycap-2.11.3.121_amd64.deb](https://github.com/RhobanDeps/flycapture), avilable on the RhobanDeps github page, is compatable with 16.04. The [readme](https://github.com/RhobanDeps/flycapture/blob/master/README) suggests using 16.04 with the following as dependencies.

> ## DEPENDENCIES
>
> To install FlyCapture2 on linux you will need to have a few
>   prerequisite libraries installed.  Below is a list of libs that
>   flycapture2 depends on.
>
> Required:
>   1) libraw1394-11
>   2) libgtkmm-2.4-dev
>   3) libglademm-2.4-dev 
>   4) libgtkglextmm-x11-1.2-dev
>   5) libusb-1.0-0 (version 1.0.17 or greater recommended)
>
> Strongly recommended:
>   Ubuntu 16.04 LTS: Linux kernel version 4.4.19-35
>   or later.

They can be installed by `sudo apt-get install libraw1394-11 libgtkmm-2.4-dev libglademm-2.4-dev libgtkglextmm-x11-1.2-dev libusb-1.0-0`.